# Customize the message returned when accessing the server url of a connexion (python) service

Tags: api, rest, service, python-3.6, connexion

I am writing a python service with [connexion](https://connexion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I have access to the swagger gui of the service via `localhost:<port>/ui`. However, when I enter `localhost:<port>` in the browser without the `/ui` ([automatically](https://connexion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#the-swagger-ui-console) added by connexion), I get the following message:

```
{
  "detail": "The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.",
  "status": 404,
  "title": "Not Found",
  "type": "about:blank"
}
```

Is it possible to customize this message ? In my case, I want `localhost:<port>` to return the following message instead:

```
{"message": "check /ui to have access to the Swagger UI"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution. Just add the following to the openspec api:

```
  /:
    get:
      operationId: path.to.function
      summary: "my personlized message"
      responses:
      ......
```